# visual studio 2015 / resharper support for angular2

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular, syntax-highlighting, resharper-10.0

I have several question about vs 2015, reshaper 10 and angular 2.

1. It exist any syntax highlighting support for html markup in ts file for visual studio 2015 or in resharper 10?

For example when I use multiline string in Component template.

```
@Component({
    selector: "hello-world",
    template: `
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#name of names">Hello {{name}}</li>
    </ul>
    `
})
```

2. When I use ng2 keywords such as #inputName, (click)="add(inputName)" in html file [visual studio show errors in markup](http://postimg.org/image/4xwjaqq33/). Any way how to fix this problem. It’s annoying.
3. I would like have intellisense support for ng2 in html. I tried find aby resharper plugin but without success.

Answer (score 6):

I just downloaded the latest version of [ReSharper 10.1 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+10.1+EAP) and it now has support for Angular 2 annotations.

I took a screenshot from my code window. Looks much better!
[image]

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to support the binding tags and proper Intellisense in HTML template files yet.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper version 2017.1 adds support for Angular2 templates. See here: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/#v2017-1-angular-2